# Use dd to copy 2 partitions to ISO

Tags: partitioning, iso-image, dd

I have a bootable 16GB USB with three partitions, I want to copy the first 2 to an ISO file. Found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/523031/dd-just-copy-partitions) but it wasn't helpful to me.

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|       |                   |                   |
|  EFI  |     7.8GB HFS+    | 7.8GB Empty Space |
|       |                   |                   |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

How can I do this with dd?

I tried with:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=Image.iso
```

But it made an image of 16GB, an image of the whole device. I just want an image from sdc1 and sdc2
PS:If I burn this image to a DVD, will it boot?

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 but I could use Windows 7 or Mac OS x Mountain Lion as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either:

1. use `if=/dev/sdc1` to just get the information from the first partition. Then do the same for /dev/sdc2 and con`cat`tenate both files.
2. Or do that and just keep the file image files. Much more flexible.
3. Or use the blocksize and count commands: E.g. `dd if=/dev/sdc of=Image bs=XX count=YY` (where XX and YY could be 1M and 10 to read the first 10MB. Adjust as needed.
4. Or since you already have an image of all of the whole thing. Just  `truncate` the file. See `man 1 truncate`.

Comment: Already thought about concatenating files but I didn't know if this would mess up the data. I'll try this.

Comment: Dd is a reblocker. It reads information from a source (if) and outputs it to another source (of). It does not reorder the data. So you can just remove the last 7.8GB. Just make sure that your calculations are correct and that you do not remove to much.