# Is it possible to make .iso from Linux Disk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-image, imaging

I want to make a .iso file from my modified Feren OS so that I can share this with my Friend and put it on my Laptop. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is this something your looking for?: https://linuxhint.com/create-iso-current-installation-ubuntu/

Comment: @mully this seems to just show me how i can put data into an .iso but i need like the whole drive with partitions etc

Comment: ISOs don't have partition tables so how would that work?  You could potentially use `dd` to create an image of the entire disk but it won't be an ISO.

Comment: A dd image *is* ISO  "for all intents and purposes" (though it might not open in Windows as an archive) according to to AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/293646/convert-dd-image-file-to-iso

Comment: I disagree with AskUbuntu @DrMoishePippik , ISOs are based on the [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) file system originally intent on providing a file system for CD ROMs.  `dd` provides a block copies through a UNIX file system of anything accessible through a UNIX device file (like /dev/sda).  Because Linux is smart enough to mount either one seamlessly doesn't make them the same.  For instance, in an ISO, where will the boot loader code get stored so that it is restored correctly?

Comment: With that said @DrMoishePippik , it does appear that you can [cram all of the data into an ISO file](https://superuser.com/questions/665714/use-dd-to-copy-2-partitions-to-iso). A trick that I did not know.  They are still not the same thing.